# "sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection" al conectarse a un servidor FTP en Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ftp

Tengo un problema con Eclipse a la hora de conectarlo con un servidor ftp.

Tengo mi proyecto, el cual, quiero que esté sincronizado con git (que ya tengo instalado el plugin). Este plugin funciona correctamente siempre y cuando se sincronice con un repositorio ya sea en GitHub ó bitbucket, etc.

El problema viene cuando quiero conectar el plugin con un ftp.

En los parametros yo tengo lo siguiente:

[image: parametros]

Cuando le doy a Next, me da el siguiente error:

[image: error]

Alguno sabe de que puede ser?, gracias.

Comment: quizas esto lo pueda ayudar es de SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038026/using-java-class-httpsurlconnection#answer-3038050 Saludos

Comment: Ya he probado a añadir esas librerias y sigue dando problemas

Comment: esto me lo acaban de comentar pero no se si te servira, me dijeron que si eliminas ftp:/// de la URI si ya esta clonado funciona, pero no se si esto tendra mucho sentido Saludos

Comment: Quitando lo de ftp:// da el siguiente error: Transport Error: Cannot get remote repository refs.
user@dominio.com/mag.git: connection failed.

Comment: pero por lo que acabo de ver, cuando no lo pones, automaticamente realiza una conexión por ssh, yo quiero que haga una conexión ftp.

Comment: Que versión de java tienes instalado en tu equipo?

Comment: Version 8 Actualizacion 66

Answer (score 1):

En tu configuración `URI`:

```
ftp://user:password@domminio.com/mag.git
```

elimina el protocolo ya que lo tienes definido como `ftp`, trata únicamente con:
`URI`:

`user:password@domminio.com/mag.git`